# FragmentActivity suddenly finishes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two layouts `main_layout.xml` and other `search_result_layout.xml`. I have a `SearchView` in  `main_layout.xml`, when I `submit` the `QueryText` in `onQueryTextSubmit()` method of `SearchView` the `FragmentActivity` finishes and my `Application` closes suddenly, no any `Exception` occurs and no any `LogCat` is traced.

code for my `FragementActivity` is :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_it);
    progressBar = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    serviceUtils = AonawareDictServiceUtils.getInstance();
    word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word_tv);
    defination = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.defination_tv);       
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            new AsyncTask<String, Void, AonawareDictServiceWordInfo>() {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                protected AonawareDictServiceWordInfo doInBackground(
                        String... params) {

                    try {
                        AonawareDictServiceUtils.getInstance();
                        Log.e("TAG", "Data recieved");
                        return serviceUtils.queryWord(DefineItActivity.this, AonawareDictServiceUtils.ID_CIDE, searchView.getQuery().toString());
                    } catch (SAXParseException e) {

                        Log.e("TAG", "No data recieved");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(AonawareDictServiceWordInfo result) {
                    word.setText(result.getWord());
                    defination.setText(result.getWordDefination());
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            return false;
        }
    });

    changeFragment(new SearchFragment());
}

private void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment){

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, "fragment")
            .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
            .commit();
}
```

and my `SearchFragment` is :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result_layout, container, false);
    return parentView;
}
```

please suggest me a solution in this case.

Comment: your `AsyncTask` should be executed with the params `null, null, null` ?

Comment: yes and I'm successful getting data from `return serviceUtils.queryWord(DefineItActivity.this, AonawareDictServiceUtils.ID_CIDE, searchView.getQuery().toString());` but `App` closes why?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what this method is doing, but the fact that it needs an Activity as param could be the problem, since doInBackground does not run in UI Thread

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in `FragmentActivity.onPause()` and checked the stack trace to see what triggered the the change?

Comment: @donfuxx No that is not the `Problem`, because when I use `Activity` not `FragmentActivity` , and only `main_layout.xml` and place all the `Views` of `search_result_layout.xml` in that then the `App` works fine. but the `Fragment` and `FragmentAcitivty` causes the problem.